# Breadcrumb component for multi level navigation menu

Tags: experience-cloud, experience-builder-page

I have created a multi level navigation menu in `experience cloud builder`.

Menu Hierarchy would be something like this.

```
Parent page A
   Child Page 1
   Child Page 2
   Child Page 3
```

I don't see any `breadcrumb` component to add here which will navigate me to the `parent` page if I am in any of the `child` page.

Only `breadcrumb` component I can find if I am in `Topic Detail page`.

I have created a lightning cmp but it's not dynamic with the child page I am selecting.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:breadcrumbs>
        <lightning:breadcrumb label="Parent Page" href="path/to/place/1"/>
        <lightning:breadcrumb label="Child Page" href="path/to/place/2"/>
    </lightning:breadcrumbs>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Do you see the navigational path on the Topic Detail page after publishing in your community? Based on [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_breadcrumb.htm&type=5) "You can use the Breadcrumb component in an Experience Builder site template on topic, article, or feed detail pages"

Comment: I can see the breadcrumb for the topic but I don’t see the same component for navigational hierarchy